# Schedular that have length in place of days in the attached image

Tags: d3.js, charts, schedule, syncfusion, dhtmlx

[I want to develop a similar chart that shall have length on horizontal axis in place of Days. I have tried several libraries like Syncfusion,Dhtmlx but no one is supporting this. Can you help me please?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWdDh.png)

Answer (score 0):

After the thorough investigation, according to current Scheduler architecture it is not feasible to render the length scale on the x-axis instead of dates. Because of the scheduler is primarily designed to function with the hours and dates. As a result, it is not possible to remove the dates and replace them with a length scale in the Scheduler as per your request.